# How can I make a div pop up after a form submits

Tags: php, javascript

I have this contact form on my website, the things i want to do is that since i have the contact button on all pages, when the user clicks the contact button, the contact form pops out.That has been achieved. Then after the user clicks the submit button on the contact form, instead of taking the user to the result page, i want a result div to just popup on that same current page the user is on.How can I go about this?

Comment: Is the form submitting using ajax? Or does it perform a post of the whole page? That is are you using plain HTML for your form <form action="something" method="post"> or are you using something like jQuery's $.post()?

Comment: @luisperezphd, am using Jquery to validate the forms, then am using php to post the form to an email address. the way it's designed, is that my php script returns a success url if the email is sent. now what i want is, instead of using that success url to redirect me to the result page, i just simply want a popup div. what am guessing is that, i can use jquery to detect a specific hash that can trigger a div to popup but don't know how it can be done too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm to ajaxify the form, and in the callback set innerHTML of your div accordingly.

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
  $('#someDiv').html("Success!");
});
```

Comment: Please don't recommend a plugin that replicates behaviour that can be written in approximately 10 lines.

Comment: @JamWaffles why is that ? Is it bad to reuse instead of remake the wheel each time? I don't think so!

Comment: Is it bad to add the overhead of downloading the plugin file, as well as having it parsed by the browser? I _do_ think so. Is it bad to download a large plugin that has far more functionality than is actually needed, that just serves to slightly simplify already simple methods? I _do_ think so.

Comment: @JamWaffles that's an overstatement, there are many pros/cons. Please let's not get into [bikeshedding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding).

Comment: I'm not bikeshedding (good term, btw), and I don't see my comment as an overstatement; the form plugin is rather large and adds functionality that a simple `$.ajax()` call with a `success:` (or otherwise) handler.

Comment: @clyfe wow thanks, this is exactly, what i was looking for, with this i can implement what i want.Thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use this pattern:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "test.php",
     data: "do=" + do,
     success: function(dta){
       $("#alert").html("Success");
     }
  });
```

Comment: How can I implement this?  my form is processed on the server side, i need to provide a kind of return url that can possibly trigger the div am looking for.

Comment: I can't understand what are you saying, can you say an example please.